# How to migrate Magento1.x module to Magento2.x?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, code-migration

If i want to migrate Magento1.x module to Magento2.x how we can do this and how would be good according to its accuracy it should be a good approach?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?